# Bootstrap 5.3 theme toggle works only one time

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm reading the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#javascript) of Bootstrap 5.3 in order to enable the toggle between dark and light theme using JavaScript. I included the script in my page and added the `data-bs-theme` attribute to the `html` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" data-bs-theme="dark">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

Where `theme.js` includes the script on the doc page.
then I put a button in my page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary me-3" data-bs-toggle="button" data-bs-theme-value="light">Dark/light theme switch</button>
```

When I click on the `button` it swaps the `data-bs-theme` attribute from `dark` to `light`, but then it does not swap the values again on the second press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click function is assigning the theme to be whatever the `data-bs-theme-value` is. Since you're storing the selected theme to localStorage also, you can grab the value of the theme and then set it to the opposite on click.

Here's one possible option that would work:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showActiveTheme(getPreferredTheme())

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]')
      .forEach(toggle => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const theme = (getStoredTheme() || toggle.getAttribute('data-bs-theme-value')) == 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
          setStoredTheme(theme)
          setTheme(theme)
          showActiveTheme(theme, true)
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Got it thanks! But I'm still curious about how they intended to use the original script. Assigning it once it does not seem very useful...

Comment: Their intention is for you do have 2 separate buttons in a dropdown to select the theme. Just like the one in the top right corner of the navigation on their documentation page.